# Does the python interpreter simplify mathematical expressions?

Tags: python, compiler-optimization

If I had this bit of code:

```
a=6
print(a*100//50)
```

What would the python interpreter do?
Would the python interpreter see this as

```
a=6
print(a*2)
```

Or would the python interpreter see this as is, and do the `*100` and `//50`?

Comment: That depends on the interpreter.  There are quite a few Python interpreters out there.

Comment: You could run `dis.dis("print(a*100//50)")` and check for yourself.

Comment: I'm using IDLE and I guess I could try dis.dis("print(a*100/50)"), also @Julien multiplication can be done from right to left, order doesn't matter. Unless you are talking about complex numbers.

Comment: @DSOI__UNUNOCTIUM YES ORDER MATTERS, you are not dealing only with multiplications here, `*` and `/` have the same precedence so should be evaluated left to right no matter what. `12/3*2` means `(12/3)*2` which is not `12/(3*2)`!

Comment: @Julien yeah if you have the division operator but usually I see 12/3*2 as 12*(1/3)*2 so order didn't seem to matter for me. You are right I guess.

Comment: If you had written that as `100//50*a`, it would actually be simplified to `2*a` in the standard CPython interpreter.  That's *constant folding*, and has been around since Python 2.6.  The way you actually wrote it cannot be folded, since the division applies to the result of the multiplication, and Python absolutely cannot reorder those operations - `a` could very well be some user-defined object that implements them in unusual ways.

Comment: @jasonharper Great info! Thanks! How about `a=33; [a*100//50 for _ in range(10)]`? Will it detect that `a*100//50` is a constant expression? Or even `2*a`?

Comment: The only "constants" in Python are literals.  Any variable can be potentially changed after the original assignment, even if there don't appear to be any other assignments to it, so they aren't eligible for constant folding.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, but shouldn't python know that a is an integer, and therefore could reorder and do the 100//50 first?

Comment: How could it guarantee that `a` remains an integer?  Another thread could have reassigned it between the two statements, for example.

Comment: @jasonharper that is true, forgot types could change in python.